# html page getting hanged with to many d3.js radar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a radar chart dynamically based on the number of records coming from the server as json data.
For example: my json has 1000 records and I try to create radar chart to show the data but my html page getting hanged.

I tried it and it is working up to 50 charts.

[image]

Comment: If you have 1000 records to display at the same time,  your chart will be unreadable anyway. I will for example display the 25 biggest values and sum the other in one value that i will show too as "other"

Comment: for ex: i trying to generate a radar for each profile.

Comment: did you need to display all the radar's profile in the same time ? 
you can display them by letter for example ( display only the profile who start with a 'a' , then 'b' etc.. )

Comment: @sen Have you seen a site with a thousand different images, loaded together?  Trying to render a thousand chart is the problem.  A few ten d3 charts hanging browser is not, if you consider how many JS objects each chart creates so that you can manage the chart which is rendered dynamically to an graphic buffer.  At least images are simply copied.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be fixed.

Every single chart you render requires a significant portion of processing time to be built. The more charts you want to render, the more processing time it will take. There's nothing you can do about that.

Either try to condense your data into (significantly) fewer charts, or render an individual chart when a row is selected.

Or, (tell your clients to) [get a beast of a machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXOaCkbt4lI).

Comment: You could also try to cache the generated charts as images and update them from time to time.

Comment: Then you'd lose all interactive / responsive capabilities.

Comment: Hello, thanks for all your comments. i will do some work around for all the suggestions provided like generate chart via lazy loading, or top number based or capture as a image then click the image show the detailed chart. the scenario i wanted to show in portal like i have multiple property in a hotel chain, if i search a hotel the high level result will show each property and its fecilities in rader with ratings...then i click the radar to see detailed in full page.

Comment: my out put attached in the question